# Unreachable code error with no return

Tags: java

I have a program I was working on and suddenly started getting unreachable code errors at my return in my columns() method. I tried any line and it won't say anything but unreachable code. The line "return obj" is the line that can't be reached. My code is below:

```
public class Display {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int x,y;
    for(int a = 1; a < 5; a++){
        System.out.print(a + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        y = i;
        x = 1;
        for(int z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
            System.out.print(x*y + "\t");
            x++;
        }
    System.out.println();   
    }
}

public static Object[] columns() {  
    Object[] obj;
    obj = new Object[11];
    obj[0] = "x = 1, 2, 3, 4";
    for(int o = 0; 0 < 10;o++){
        obj[o+1] = "x * " + o;
    }
    return obj;
}
}
```

Comment: `0 < 10` should be `o < 10` in the `for` loop

Comment: oh my gosh thank you so much

Comment: `0 < 10` I think this should be `o < 10`? else the return statement will never be reached because zero is always less than 10.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it was caused by a simple typo. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int o = 0; o < 10;o++){
    obj[o+1] = "x * " + o;
}
return obj;
```

You are using `0<10` this loop never ends.

Answer (score 2):

`0 < 10` because thats like `while(true)`